# Only keep elements (A,B) from list1 if A=X, where (X,Y) are elements of list2.

Tags: python, bash

I require a python or preferably even bash solution to this question.
I have two lists (or rather text files):

File1:
A1 B1
A2 B2
A3 B3
...

File2:
X1 Y1
X2 Y2
X3 Y3
...

I need to calculate (BN-YN) for all N for which (AN=XN) such that file 3 looks like:

File3:
AN(=XN) BN-YN
AM(=XM) BM-YM
...

This would be easy if I could select all intersecting elements (and associate elements B) of A with X, since X is a subset of A.

Comment: what did you try so far. No point in just asking the solution of problem. Looks like an assignment

Comment: ok, show the real values for 2 files and the desired calculated output

Answer (score 1):

Awk is better suited for text manipulation tasks than bash. Here is what an awk one-liner could look like:

```
$ head file{1,2}
==> file1 <==
1 10
3 11
5 12

==> file2 <==
5 5
3 6

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a{print $1,a[$1]-$2}' file1 file2
5 7
3 5
```

The caveat here is that we store the entire `file1` in memory, so you wouldn't want to use this approach if `file1` is very large.

Comment: Let `join` handle pairing up the B and Y values: `join file1 file2 | awk '{print $1, $2 - $3}'`. (Sorting the two files first, if necessary.)

Comment: Thanks @user000001 the solution works. I don't have much experience with awk. The a[$1]-$2 output values have less than necessary precision. How would I add e.g. 'printf "%.10f\n"' to fix this?

Comment: @pqRS: You would write `{printf "%s %.10f\n",$1,a[$1]-$2}` for setting custom precision.